# How to get *tmux* experience using Powershell to work remotely on a Windows server?

Tags: powershell, ssh, tmux, powershell-remoting

For remote work on a Linux server, I can `ssh` and then `tmux` to resume my work (including stdout/stderr).

How can I get the same experience on Windows server using Powershell? I have done some basic reading on `Enter-PSSession` but that feels like ssh without tmux.

Answer (score 8):

When you use `Enter-PSSession` and exit with `Exit-PSSession`, The Session is Permanently deleted and you can't resume it.

However, You can Create a Remote Session like this:

```
$session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $ComputerName
```

And Then Connect into it

```
Enter-PSSession $session
```

This way You Can disconnect (but the session will remain connected)

```
Exit-PSSession
```

And Reconnect again (and come back to the same state)

```
Enter-PSSession $session
```

As long as `$session` variable is available the session remains open and all your work remain in the same state

To Disconnect the Session:

```
Disconnect-PSSession $session
```

To remove the Session:

```
Remove-PSSession $session
```

Comment: Thanks but I have a few follow-up questions. (1) If I want to multi-task, do I need to create multiple PSSessions? (2) If I exit a session (e.g. due to lost connection or closed laptop) while running a program that prints to stdout, what would I see when I re-enter that session?

Comment: (1) yes create multiple PSSesions, (2) as long as your powershell session open it remains open, if you want to save your  session commands, this might help as well, http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2009/12/29/saving-remote-session-to-your-local-disk.aspx